# Ordering Navigation Properties - Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading, entity-framework-4

Is there a way built into the entity framework or commonly used pattern for ordering lazy loaded navigation properties to ensure no matter how they are accessed they are always in the correct order.

I would like to avoid having to write properties or methods on partial classes if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no. Relational data has no implicit "correct" order, and the EF doesn't impose one.

Comment: Unfortunately thats what I thought might be the case.